# Convert double-byte numbers and spaces in filenames to ASCII

Tags: unicode, ascii, double-byte

Given a directory of filenames consisting of double-byte/full-width numbers and spaces (along with some half-width numbers and underscores), how can I convert all of the numbers and spaces to single-byte characters?

For example, this filename consists of a double-byte number, followed by a double-byte space, followed by some single-byte characters:

２　2_3.ext

and I'd like to change it to all single-byte like so:

2  2_3.ext

I've tried [convmv](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/58689) to convert from utf8 to ascii, but the following message appears for all files:

"ascii doesn't cover all needed characters for: *filename*"

Comment: You should specify the language. Also it would be a good idea to specify why do you want to do this, it doesn't make to much sense because you will still have other Unicode characters that cannot be converted to `ASCII`.

Comment: *"it doesn't make to much sense because you will still have other Unicode characters that cannot be converted"*

That's why I said "numbers and spaces", not all characters. I found a solution using Perl that worked perfectly (see my answer below).

*"You should specify the language."*

There was also no reason to specify the language, as I would have been happy with a solution from virtually any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your quick replies, bmargulies and bobince. I found a Perl module, [Unicode::Japanese](http://search.cpan.org/~hio/Unicode-Japanese-0.47/lib/Unicode/Japanese.pm), that helped get the job done. Here is a bash script I made (with help from [this example](http://ask.metafilter.com/16433/UNIX-Recursive-file-renaming-based-on-patterns#278485)) to convert filenames in the current directory from full-width to half-width characters:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *;do
newfile=$(echo $file | perl -MUnicode::Japanese -e'print Unicode::Japanese->new(<>)->z2h->get;')
test "$file" != "$newfile" && mv "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You need either (1) normalization from Java 1.6 (`java.text.Normalizer`), or (2) [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), or (3 (unlikely)) a product sold by the place I work.

Answer (score 1):

What tools do you have available? There are Unicode normalisation functions in several scripting languages, for example in Python:

```
for child in os.listdir(u'.'):
    normal= unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', child)
    if normal!=child:
        os.rename(child, normal)
```